# Flutter Haptic Feedback On Long Press

Tags: android, ios, flutter, haptic-feedback

How are we supposed to cause haptic feedback on long press using Flutter HapticFeedback class?

I am currently working with `HapticFeedback.selectionClick()` during my OnTapDown method, but nothing is happening.

I have also already added the vibrate permission in the android manifest file. I am using a Pixel2 XL device for testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `vibrate` plugin for that.
Add this dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
vibrate: ^0.0.4
```

Use this function in your class for vibration

```
void vibrate() async {
    bool canVibrate = await Vibrate.canVibrate;
    canVibrate ? Vibrate.feedback(FeedbackType.medium) : null;
  }
```

And call the above function from your widget when the **onLongPress** event is triggred

```
 onLongPress: () {
          vibrate();
        },
```

[More about vibrate plugin.](https://pub.dev/packages/vibrate)
Hope it helps.

Comment: (vibration) is not recognised.

Comment: @Bisclavret Remove the `if` condition, it should work, think it was mistakenly pasted from my project. See the edit.